# Alert Dialog with EditText and positive negative button

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to create a DialogFragment as

```
    public class PlaceFragment extends DialogFragment {
      public PlaceFragment() {
      }

      public static PlaceFragment newInstance() {
        PlaceFragment placeFragment = new PlaceFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putDouble("Latitude", 12.3456);
        placeFragment.setArguments(args);
        return placeFragment;
      }
     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container, false);
    AlertDialog.Builder placePicker = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    placePicker.setView(R.layout.fragment_place)
        .setTitle("Enter Latitude and Longitude")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
//    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container);
    return v;
  }
    }
```

which should be called as:

```
case R.id.action_geolocate:
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        PlaceFragment placeFragment = PlaceFragment.newInstance();
        placeFragment.show(fm, "");
        return true;
```

But, as you can see, this is not working,as this is obviously showing the layout only, which is inflated. But I am trying to get the dialog with two line of EditText with Ok and Dissmiss button.

If I use a completely manual way, then I am getting the editText, but dont have any idea how to get those value with OkButton, like:

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Create a class extend DialogFragment
- override and implement onCreateDialog to configure how the dialog appears. Here, create a Dialog / AlertDialog, can also populate its layout here.
- In some cases, you want to implement onCreateView and handle views/actions there.

Hope this would help.

Comment: `oncreateDialog`? As far as I know that is to build the dialog all by yourself by scratch, and `oncreateView` is the proper place to add elements.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should implement

`@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

instead of

`@Override
public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

and return a dialog instead of view and i think it would be better if you do not leave the tag string in `.show(ft,"")`  empty

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right, something like this should work:

```
 public class DialogEnterExit extends DialogFragment {

        public interface EnterExitDialogListener {
            void onFinishEditDialog(String event, String place, Location location);
        }

        EnterExitDialogListener mListener;

        private static final String TAG = DialogEnterExit.class.getSimpleName();

        AppCompatDialog mDialog;
        String mPlace;
        Location mLocation;



        public static DialogEnterExit newInstance(String place, Location location) {
            DialogEnterExit f = new DialogEnterExit();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("PLACE", place);
            args.putParcelable("LOCATION", location);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mPlace = getArguments().getString("PLACE");
            mLocation = getArguments().getParcelable("LOCATION");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_enter_exit_dialog,null);

            final RadioButton enter = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_enter);
            final RadioButton exit = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_exit);
            TextView place = view.findViewById(R.id.place_picked);

            place.setText(mPlace);

            enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (mListener != null) {

     mListener.onFinishEditDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_transition_entered), mPlace, 
      mLocation);
                    }
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (mListener != null) {

     mListener.onFinishEditDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_transition_exited), mPlace, 
   mLocation);
                    }

                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            builder
                    .setView(view)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title_event))
                    .setCancelable(true);

            mDialog = builder.create();
            return mDialog;
        }


        @Override
        public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);

            // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
            try {
                // Instantiate the EditNameDialogListener so we can send events to the 
           host
                mListener = (EnterExitDialogListener) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
                throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement EnterExitDialogListener"  );
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();

            mListener = null;
        }
    }
```

and the view in xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="place:"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/place_picked"
                android:hint="place name"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_enter"
            android:text="@string/geofence_transition_entered"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_exit"
            android:text="@string/geofence_transition_exited"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and to use:

```
 android.location.Location loc = new android.location.Location("");
    loc.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    loc.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

  DialogEnterExit dialogEnterExit = DialogEnterExit.newInstance(location.getName(), loc);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(dialogEnterExit, "enter exit dialog").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```